# IR Receiver(rx) not receiving a continuously signal from ir led(tx) rather than it receiving at first instant of time while transmitting

Tags: arduino, frequency, infrared, duty-cycle

I m making line follower bot using sensor-(IR RX and IR led).
Here is my Circuit for IR tX
[image: IR TX circuit]
Circuit for rx
[image: rx]

This both circuit are working properly my problem is IR Rx not receiving signal continuously it receive for 5-8 then it stop receiving even ir led continuously transmit.once again if you start from first it work after few seconds behave same it wont get any signal

Also i tried with different manufacturer ir rx it behave same but receiving time will very for each ir rx
check out this 4 different ir rx all are 38khz frequency
[image]

My ir led tx circuit will generate nearly 35 khz so i tried changing R2 value 18k but it behave same

How to fix this problem can anyone suggest

also i noticed that i m using 50-percent duty cycle with 38khz in tx side is it impact if i go for 90 percent duty cycle.How it is different from 50 and 90 percent duty cycle while same frequency what behave it changes

Answer (score 2):

Your IR receiver Q1 is upside down. You need to swap the collector and emitter pins. Current flows from positive to negative in the direction of the PN junction arrow.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This type of receiver is optimized for IR-remote signales. It uses an AGC (Automatic Gain Control) to eliminate background noise. To be able to distinguish between the signal and the background noise, the singal must *not be continous*, it must be modulated (on/off), for instance 1ms on / 1 ms off. (This is *on top of* the 38 kHZ modulation.) If it is continously on, it will at first be recognised as a valid signal, but after a short time the AGC will kick in and the signal will no longer be recognised (at least not reliably).

[image]

So, you need a second 555 to key your IR signal. At the receiver you already have a crude integrator (C1), that might be enough to bridge the gaps in the transmitted signal.